# How to keep ASP.NET Core minimal APIs from returning the full stack trace when there is an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, postman, minimal-apis

I am writing an API using ASP.NET core's minimal API setup in C#. How can I keep it from returning the stack trace for internal server errors?

For instance, if the below code throws an SQL error while processing the data it gets returned and shows up in the return body in Postman. I tried putting these try-catch statements in (as suggested in the answers to similar questions for standard ASP.NET core), but they don't prevent the errors from being returned.

```
try{
    /// <summary>
    /// Receives updates sent from the cellphone app, parses the JSON, and sends the result to be processed for the database.
    /// </summary>
    app.MapPost("/sendUpdates", [Authorize] async (IDataService dataService, HttpRequest request) => {
        try {
            //Parse JSON data from request body
            string bodyStr = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            //Remove the "while(1);" that is at the beginning to deter code injectors' data stealing
            bodyStr = bodyStr.Replace("while(1);", "");
            //JsonSerializer automatically converts from the JSON string to a DataUpdateDTO. 
            DataUpdateDTO? cellphoneData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataUpdateDTO>(bodyStr);
            //Process code in database
            return await dataService.processData(cellphoneData);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Console.Write(ex);
            return Results.StatusCode(500);
        }
    });
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.Write(ex);
}
```

I realize this seems similar to other questions about avoiding developer exception page middleware, but the issue is different. It's not a question about how to disable the developer exception page middleware; it's a question about how to disable exception returning *without knowing that the developer exception page is to blame*. The question about the middleware does not mention what it does, only that the poster wants to disable it.

Comment: Do you see the exception details only in the `Development` environment? `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` is added _impliclity_ when you use `WebApplication`, but only in the `Development` environment.

Comment: It shows up in Postman - it's being returned in the response body.

Comment: Sure, I saw that. It's about the environment you're running in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-6.0?view=aspnetcore-6.0#developer-exception-page-middleware-added-automatically.

Comment: Why do you have a try/catch _around_ `app.MapPost`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin that was the problem! After switching from development to production, the try-catch caught the error and it didn't get returned.

Comment: @gunr2171 the try-catch around ```app.MapPost``` was to catch errors coming from the parameters in ```app.MapPost``` - I realize it probably doesn't really do much.

Comment: @GuruStan: I just edited to explain why this is not a duplicate. Minimal API's tutorial/overview on the Microsoft site doesn't explain what the Developer Exception Page Middleware does, so I and other newcomers to Minimal APIs don't always know that it is the reason errors are returned in the response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KirkLarkin pointed out, the issue was that I was running the app in the Development environment and not the Production environment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-6.0?view=aspnetcore-6.0#developer-exception-page-middleware-added-automatically explains that the Development environment now always acts as if the app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() had be explicitly called in the code. Switching the launchsettings.json environment variables to be Production instead of Development solved the problem.